# De Broglie Wavelength of a particle at the turning point of a fountain

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wave-particle-duality, wavelength, interferometry

If you think about an atom which is launched in some kind of straight fountain, upward in the gravitational field.
At the turning point the velocity and therefore the momentum of the particle seems to be zero, leading to an infinite de Broglie wavelength, which makes no sense at all.

So what does actually happen with the wavelength of a particle at the turning point?

Comment: Why do you think an infinite de Broglie wavelength doesn't make sense? It's only infinite in the reference frame where the particle is at rest. You can have a finite wavelength in a different reference frame.

Comment: It happens that there is no turning point in QM. You are mixing classical and quantum concepts in an uncontrolled way.

The very first lesson QM teaches us is that there is no trajectory. Without trajectory, no turning point.

Answer (score 1):

I think that that you  thinking about the $V(x)=\lambda x$ Airy equation version of the Shrodinger equation. There  for any given energy there is a "turning point" at which the local wavenumber $k=2\pi/\lambda = (-i\partial_x \psi)/\psi$ becomes zero (and the local wavelength becomes infinite). At the turning point  the character of the Airy-function solution changes from oscillating to decaying.  Look at the article and plots of the Airy function in Wikipedia.